# Why don't I see any output from a print inside of thread::spawn?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust

I want to print inside a closure which is passed to `thread::spawn` but I don't see any output. I tried launching this piece of code on my computer, then in Rust playground. Flushing inside the closure does not give any results. What is the problem?

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    println!("run main process");
    thread::spawn(|| {
        println!("Hello from a thread!");
    });
}
```

Comment: You can park the main thread to [Play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc17256e0faf9df44fbc1b9548605847) around

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that, immediately after spawning the thread, the `main` function returns, terminating the program. Therefore, the thread never actually has time to run. You can put a `sleep` call at the end of `main` to give the spawned thread time to run.

Comment: Don't sleep. [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join)